# How do I make my react-bootstrap-table-next maintain the same column width for all screen resolutions (Mobile responsive)?

Tags: reactjs, responsive, react-bootstrap-table

I am using the BootstrapTable component from react-bootstrap-table-next. I am trying to create a page where this table must use the entire width of the screen. If the screen resolution drops down to iPad and mobile, the table must be scrollable. Instead, my table columns are shrinking. Thanks.

columns:

```
columns = [
            {
                text: "Item",
                dataField: "item",
                key: "item",
                editable: false,
                style: {
                    width:"15vw"
                },
                formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => {
                    let data = row
                    console.log('row data ---> ', data)
                    return (<Select
                        defaultValue={data.item ? data.item : "Select..."}
                        options={catalogue}
                        styles={customStyles}
                        name="items"
                        value={this.state.selectedItem[rowIndex]}
                        onChange={(event) => this.onItemSelected(event, rowIndex, 'item')}
                    />)
                }
            },
            {
                text: "Unit Price",
                dataField: "unitPrice",
                key: "unitPrice",
                align: "right",

            },
            {
                text: "Quantity",
                dataField: "quantity",
                key: "quantity",
                align: "right",
            },
            {
                text: "Amount",
                dataField: "amount",
                key: "amount",
                editable: false,
                align: "right",
            },
            {
                text: <Icon name="edit" />,
                dataField: "action",
                isDummyField: true,
                editable: false,
                formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => {
                    return (<Icon name="trash" style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={() => this.deleteRow(rowIndex)} />)
                }
            }

        ];
```

data:

```
data = [
{
    item:"Apple",
    unitPrice:1000,
    quantity:1,
    amount:1000
}
]
```

component:

```
<BootstrapTable
     keyField="index"
     data={this.state.dataSource}
     columns={columns}
/>
```